# STM32DUINO and analogRead for stm32f103c8t6

Tags: arduino, stm32

I have custom board on which I can upload my code generated from platformio and as board `bluepill_f103c8`. And I can make led blink etc. but when I want to do analogRead it always returns 0.

I'm trying to read from `PA8` pin.

In my setup I put that pin as INPUT_ANALOG, do I need to do something else in order to get the reading?

Voltage that's on pin is about 0.25V that I'm trying to read.

Comment: the experts are here https://www.stm32duino.com

Comment: Interesting, you have designed the board without even reading the documentation, hoping that "magical" Arduino will do everything.

Comment: @tono-nam, you don't have the same problem. the problem was specific for the PA8 pin. so we would need to see your sketch as a new Question

Answer (score 2):

According to [STM32F103 Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103ze.pdf), page 34, any of 3 onboard ADCs simply do not have the ability to connect to PA8. PA8 can only work as simple GPIO (default, reads only 0 and 1), or as USART1_CK, TIM1_CH1, MCO in alternative configuration.
Arduino can use it as PWM output, or software USART, but there is no way to get analog reading from it.
If you *really* need to read analog voltage coming to that line, you would have to modify your board and solder PA8 to one of PA0..PA7, PB0..PB1, PC0..PC5 and re-configure ADC to read from that line.

@TonoNam, regarding your problem: unless PA1 is permanently damaged, it is fully capable of working with ADC, so there is something wrong with initialization or reading procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Reference the pinout diagram here https://wiki.stm32duino.com/index.php?title=File:Bluepillpinout.gif

`analogRead` will only work with the pins which have associated ADC channels.
So this is `PA0` through `PA7`, and then `PB0` and `PB1`, so I guess this is your issue.

Looks like `PA8` is a PWM output.

Comment: I though these pins can be re-programmed? Or that's doable via CubeMX and similar, but not via stm32duino?

Comment: I believe you would need to alter the actual configuration registers to do that. the stm32duino setup correlates to this pinout afaik. I guess you can override this, but I've not tried it.

Comment: @ShP Yes, it is possible to re-configure pins, and arduino framework will attempt to do that for you automatically, but not anything-to-anything, there are limitations in silicon.